# Issues with switching fullscreen apps

Tags: dock, switching

When I open a few fullscreen applications and try to switch to one of them by clicking on dock icon, I'm getting empty desktop with just the applications menu instead.

Second click on the same icon brings me to already open app.

Are there any settings to open running fullscreen app on first click?

I'm using macOS Ventura 13.2.1.